# Assembly:Access 2D array

Tags: assembly, nasm, cpu-registers

I am trying to make a small ping pong game in nasm assembly(thats the way i learn languages :) )
but i am having a problem ,i cant access any item of a list

**my code**:

```
mov eax,counter                  ;counter=2 double checked 
mov esi,bitmap_data+eax*4        ;copy the 2nd item of the array in to esi
```

bitmap data is in.bss section

```
bitmap_data:    resd 100
```

**tried**:

```
mov eax,2                         
mov esi,[bitmap_data+eax*4]       ;copy the 2nd item of the array in to esi
```

this is not saving in the esi the correct (2th) element of the list while the following is doing it right

```
mov esi,[bitmap_data+2*4]
```

but i need to be able to change the item that i am getting  by using a variable

Comment: "this is not saving in the esi the correct (2th) element"  Which element _is_ it saving then? It would probably be a good idea to fire up a debugger (Ollydbg, gdb, the Visual Studio debugger, or whatever you prefer) and step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the memory access in square brackets like so:

```
mov esi,[bitmap_data+eax*4]
```

That should make the assembler happy.

**Update, per your update:**
Try breaking up your instructions a bit. Try:

```
mov eax, counter
shl eax, 2
add eax, bitmap_data
mov esi, [eax]
```

Any change?

Comment: well ,the error stops but its still not saving the correct element of the array in to esi

Answer (score 0):

What's `counter`? Highly likely you want:

```
mov eax, [counter]
mov esi, [bitmap_data + eax * 4]
```

The "first" (zeroth) item in your array will show up when `eax` = 0. When `eax` = 2, you'd get the "third" item in the array. Which one are you looking for?